# Mouse-clicks do not work sometimes

Tags: mouse, mouse-click, dell-studio

My mouse does sometimes not Right/left-click. By sometimes I mean on average every 5th click. It looks as if the click just simply did not happen. I tried this with 3 different mice and the behavior is the same. I know for a fact that those mice are not broken or damaged. Also I have two operating systems: Windows 7 Ultimate and openSUSE. On both systems the same behavior occurs. The last thing I tried is 3 different USB slots. Again: Same behavior.

My Hardware is a DELL Studio 1537 Notebook.

I also tried to uninstall and reinstall my Mouse-drivers.

Has anyone got a clue what may be going wrong?

Comment: Have you actually tested your for a fact not broken mouse with a different computer?

Comment: @Daniel Beck Of course

Answer (score 0):

If it happens with multiple mice and multiple operating systems on the same computer, but does not happen with the same mice on other computers, it could be a problem with the motherboard.  Check your motherboard BIOS to see if an update is available.

Comment: Hmm I also think it's because of the mainboard. But there is no update on the Dell website. Also this happened from one day to the other. Is it possible that the mainboard is partly broken?

Comment: It could be a loose connection on the motherboard that may have been become aggravated by bumping the laptop.  Do other USB devices work?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it depends on a BIOS version (why should it suddenly stop working), so updates won't help. Could be that there's a hardware failure on the USB bus. Are you having issues with any other USB devices?

Comment: Another possibility would be a conflict between the built-in trackpad and an external mouse.  Use the Dell utilities to disable the trackpad and see if the mouse works.